# What is wrong with the batch_size of the following tensorflow code?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

The following Tensorflow code, which I was using to check a small technique, does regression.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_size], name="input_data")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None], name="input_data")

W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", [input_size, blocks[0]], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1))
b1 = tf.get_variable("b1", [blocks[0]])
Lw = tf.nn.l2_loss(W1)

W2 = tf.get_variable("W2", [blocks[0],  blocks[1]], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1))
b2 = tf.get_variable("b2", [blocks[1]])
Lw = Lw + tf.nn.l2_loss(W2)

W3 = tf.get_variable("W3", [blocks[1],  blocks[2]], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1))
b3 = tf.get_variable("b3", [blocks[2]])
Lw = Lw + tf.nn.l2_loss(W3)

W4 = tf.get_variable("W4", [blocks[2],  output_size], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1))
b4 = tf.get_variable("b4", [output_size])
Lw = Lw + tf.nn.l2_loss(W4)

op1 = tf.sigmoid(tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(x,W1),b1));
op2 = tf.sigmoid(tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(op1,W2),b2));
op3 = tf.sigmoid(tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(op2,W3),b3));
out = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(op3,W4),b4);

loss1 = tf.nn.l2_loss(out-y)

loss = loss1 + reg_param * Lw
```

here `input_size`, `reg_param`, `blocks` are input to the function. And `None` is the placeholder for batch_size of the network.

During training whenever I use `batch_szie = 1`, I get correct output. The network converges to desired output after about 6,000 iterations and I get output error around ~0.001. But whenever I use `batch_size=2` or more the code does not converge at all and I tried upto 100,000 iterations yet the mean output error on training data is like ~0.2.

At first I thought some operations went wrong. However, during testing I have changed `batch_size` to upto 50 and saw that the test results are correct (when trained using `batch_size=1` during training). So I think, the forward operation is okay.

IN summary, I am at a loss here. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? What could be done to remove this discrepency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This correction on `line 2` fixes everything:

```
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1], name="input_data")
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer, so that the question looks indeed answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer